# Generating JSON out of space-separated fields with grouping constraints using awk

Tags: awk

I have a space-separated file which lists tokens, lemmas and their corresponding parts of speech. The file is sorted alphabetically so that we can be sure that all non-unique tokens are in subsequent lines, like this:

```
token1 lemma1 NOUN
token2 lemma1 NOUN
token3 lemma2 PRON
token3 lemma3 NOUN
token3 lemma4 NOUN
token3 lemma5 VERB
token4 lemma5 VERB
token5 lemma4 NOUN
token6 lemma4 NOUN
token7 lemma6 ADJ
token8 lemma7 ADV
```

The goal is to produce a JSON output with the simple $token:$lemma pairs for unique tokens, and nested $token:[{$pos:$lemma},{$pos:$lemma}] pairs for non-unique tokens. In other words, we want to disambiguate non-unique tokens with a compact JSON notation.

The additional complexity stems from the fact a second level of nesting will be needed when one token can correspond to two different lemmas that have the same part of speech (in our example: token3 can correspond to lemma3 and lemma4 which are both nouns).

The expected output is this:

```
{
    "token1": "lemma1",
    "token2": "lemma1",
    "token3": [
        {"PRON": "lemma2"},
        {
            "NOUN": [
                "lemma3",
                "lemma4"
            ]
        },
        {"VERB": "lemma5"}
    ],
    "token4": "lemma5",
    "token5": "lemma4",
    "token6": "lemma4",
    "token7": "lemma6",
    "token8": "lemma7"
}
```

I would like to learn how to do this using awk. This is a more complex version of the well-known awk feature, where you can treat the first field as a key and then check whether the key has changed from line to line, but my awk skills are not advanced enough for the particular requirements of this task.

I will greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

here is the main logic, without json formatting...

assumes sorted input in first key.

```
$ awk '{k=$1 SUBSEP $3; c1[$1]++; f3[$3]; c3[k]++; 
       t[k]=((k in t)?t[k]",":"") $2} 
   END {for(k in c1) 
          for(v in f3) 
             if(c1[k]==1) 
               {if((k,v) in t) print k,t[k,v] } 
             else {if(c3[k,v]==1) print (pk==k?"":k),v,t[k,v]; 
                   else print (pk==k?"":k),v,"[", t[k,v], "]"; pk=k}}' file        

token1 lemma1
token2 lemma1
token3 PRON lemma2
 NOUN [ lemma3,lemma4 ]
 VERB lemma5
token4 lemma5
token5 lemma4
token6 lemma4
```

Comment: I can see that it works for the general logic but I still can't figure out how to go from here to the required output. Many thanks for effort anyway!